# Quick Whitepoint-based Calculation

Tags: color, color-white

I have an LED device that shines exactly one color. I know the RGB of that color, it's `rgb(190, 215, 255)` on a color-calibrated monitor.

I have several other LED devices I'd like to display the same color. I know the whitepoints of those devices compared to a color calibrated monitor. How can I "reverse calculate" that RGB to display given a whitepoint? For example, one device has the whitepoint of `rgb(255, 210, 195)` (that is, when I tell this device to shine that color, it shines white). Through painstaking trial and error, it looks like when the device shines `rgb(245, 195, 255)`, the colors match. I can't do this with every device.

Is there some equation or calculation to get an rgb code to shine that specific color? I know Photoshop has the ability to do the calculation in the opposite direction (setting the whitepoint of an image), but I couldn't find anything for the reverse direction.

Comment: What color a device shows as on a calibrated monitor is entirely dependent upon the processing applied to the assumed calibration photo (*i.e.* I'm assuming you're taking a photo of a white card and displaying that on your monitor). Also, any calibration that involves one color channel fully saturated, as in your (190,215,255) is doomed to failure because there's no way to tell how far *past* 255 the light is putting out in the blue channel. Your calibration shot needs to be exposed so that all three channels have values below 255 (or the 12-bit or 14-bit equivalent in the raw sensor data).

Comment: What colorspace is your color calibrated monitor in? If you are using, for instance, Photoshop or a color managed app, then it's only necessary to know the image tagged colorspace that contains (190,215,255).

Comment: @MichaelC If the OP is measuring the LED indirectly with a camera there's going to be other issues beyond saturation such as the S curve applied by the camera. The best approach is illuminant a "white card" placed on the monitor next to a displayed image filled with RGB values using a colorspace such as sRGB. Adjust the RGB values to match. The white card also needs to be very neutral such as a matte paper with no OBA and tint.